# What members do I need to add to a PowerShell module manifest file in order to export Cmdlets from multiple files?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

Currently, I have a number of `*.ps1` Cmdlet files, each providing a different function, e.g.:

- `Encode-File.ps1`
- `Decode-File.ps1`

Now, I want to convert these into a single module, so I can have their functionality at the ready.

First of all, I guess I will have to edit the above Cmdlet files so they will be providing corresponding Cmdlet functions instead of executing their code immediately.

Next, I would need to add a manifest file (`.psd1`) to the folder where these files exist.

What would I need to add to the manifest file, so when I write `Import-Module Manifest.psd1`, all Cmdlet functions will be available to my PowerShell session?

Comment: The common file extension for PowerShell scripts is `.ps1`, not `.ps`

Comment: A plethora of information on how to create a PowerShell module is available. SO is a place to bring source code that does not work. This is fully described at https://stackoverflow.com/help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common solution to this is to load the functions into a nested script module file.

Create a new script module file (`*.psm1`), and write a simple dot-sourcing harness, like so:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$exportedCommands = foreach ($scriptFile in Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -File -Filter *-*.ps1) {
  # dot-source file (loads the function definitions into module scope)
  . $scriptFile.FullName

  # output the function name for export
  $scriptFile.BaseName
}

# Export commands from the nested module
Export-ModuleMember -Function $exportedCommands
```

Then in your module manifest, specify:

```
  RootModule = 'moduleName.psm1'
```

If the scripts are additional scripts designed to work with a binary module, import the script module as a "nested module" instead:

```
  NestedModules = @('moduleName.psm1')
```

In order for auto-discovery of commands to work prior to module import, make sure you also explicitly list the exported functions in the manifest:

```
  FunctionsToExport = @('Encode-File', 'Decode-File')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was hoping to get around the script module file by just referering to separate files (regardless of their file extensions) in the manifest file. Isn't this a feasible way to do this?

Comment: @AxD There's no way around that for a script module, not that I know of at least. You could use the `*.psm1` file to read, parse and invoke the function definitions from your arbitrary-file-extension files, but you won't be able to use them directly. All the module directives in the manifest will expect paths ending in one of `.dll` (eg. an assembly containing binary cmdlets), `.ps[md]1` (a module file or another manifest), or `cdxml` (an XML file containing CIM command definitions)

Comment: Thanks again for your valuable comment! – So, if I get you right, in my case a manifest file would be inappropriate and redundant. All I needed was a `*.psm1` calling my `*.ps1` files, each declaring their functions, and that'll suffice for these functions to be present in the current session, am I right?

Comment: A manifest file would still be _very appropriate_ - but you need a `*.psm1` no matter what, yes :)